# Table 'todoblog.users' doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a small todo blog using sequelize. But I get stacked in this error. The table is not created. I created the database using SQL, then I used sequelize in the model and controller.

schema.sql
(here I created a database and run it manually in the terminal)

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS toDoBlog;
CREATE DATABASE toDoBlog;
USE toDoBlog;
```

connection.js
(Here when I'm connecting to the database)

```
// connection
const sequelize = new Sequelize("toDoBlog", "name", "password", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  host: "localhost",
});

// testing connection to database
sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
  });
module.exports = sequelize;
```

userModel.js
(creating the table and define it)

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const connection = require("../connexion/connexion.js");

const User = connection.define("user", {
  user_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
  email: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
  password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
  createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
});

module.exports = User;
```

userController.js
(create/find/delete operations)

```
const UserModel = require("../database/Model/userModel.js");

module.exports.createOne = async (req, res) => {
  const info = req.body;
  console.log(info);
  const user = await UserModel.create({
    name: info.name,
    email: info.email,
    password: "hash(info.password)",
  });
};
```

userRouter.js
(router for the controllers)

```
const userController = require("../controllers/userController.js");
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.post("/createOne", userController.createOne);

module.exports = router;
```

index.js
(main file)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const connextion = require("./database/connexion/connexion.js");
const userRouter = require("./routers/userRouter.js");
// const blogRouter = require("./routers/blogRouter.js");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("express working");
});

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// to link the front. I need to get more info about it.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../react-client/dist"));

app.use("/api/user", userRouter);
// app.use("/api/blogs", blogRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

this is the error

```
[nodemon] starting `node server/index.js`
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Connection has been established successfully.
{ name: 'SEMER', email: 'semer', password: 'smeer' }
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`name`,`email`,`password`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);
C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:256
        return new sequelizeErrors.DatabaseError(err);
               ^

DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: Table 'todoblog.users' doesn't exist       
    at Query.formatError (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:256:16)
    at Query.run (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:68:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:619:16
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.insert (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:748:21)       
    at async model.save (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:3954:35)
    at async Function.create (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2207:12)
    at async module.exports.createOne (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\server\controllers\userController.js:6:16) {
  parent: Error: Table 'todoblog.users' doesn't exist
      at Packet.asError (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
      at Prepare.execute (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:425:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:329:20)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:304:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:279:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:218:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
    errno: 1146,
    sqlState: '42S02',
    sqlMessage: "Table 'todoblog.users' doesn't exist",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`name`,`email`,`password`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      'SEMER',
      'semer',
      'hash(info.password)',
      '2021-03-04 16:57:41',
      '2021-03-04 16:57:41'
    ]
  },
  original: Error: Table 'todoblog.users' doesn't exist
      at Packet.asError (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:712:17)
      at Prepare.execute (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:425:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:75:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\semer\Desktop\testing skills\toDoBlog\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:82:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:329:20)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:304:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:279:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:218:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
    errno: 1146,
    sqlState: '42S02',
    sqlMessage: "Table 'todoblog.users' doesn't exist",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`name`,`email`,`password`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      'SEMER',
      'semer',
      'hash(info.password)',
      '2021-03-04 16:57:41',
      '2021-03-04 16:57:41'
    ]
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`,`name`,`email`,`password`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);',
  parameters: [
    'SEMER',
    'semer',
    'hash(info.password)',
    '2021-03-04 16:57:41',
    '2021-03-04 16:57:41'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Did you try ```sequelize.sync()``` ? What happened then

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it. I remember that I did something similar with Mysql without this kind of problem.

Comment: `sequelize db:migrate` ?, you created migration file ?

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize : check this project